# reduce number in magnitude to 5 digits

Tags: number-theory, ratio

I am looking to reduce any 10 digit number to a 5 digit number using a scale factor without any decimal numbers.

I would like it to be a whole number in keeping with a constant magnitude or constant scale factor of the original 10 digit number.

i.e 9999999999 to 99999
i.e XXXXXXXXXX to XXXXX then can in theory XXXXX to XXXXXXXXXX

I am not sure if there is a formula available to do this.  Any options to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like $f(x) = \lfloor x/100000\rfloor$? (That is, divide by $100000$ and throw away the remainder.)

Comment: Hi there,  Thanks for the response.  But the formula must work for every 10 digit number and be a whole number.  i.e 9583405930 / 100000 =  95834.0593 .  This would not work as it has (.0593).  I need a formula/method to reduce the number to a whole number (95834/Other) and back again to the original 9583405930.

Comment: There is no positive number (other than $1$) that evenly divides every $10$-digit number. Or, for that matter, every $1$-digit number. Maybe I misunderstand what you really mean?

Comment: Thanks,  What I asking for may not be possible.  However I am open to other ways to achieve the goal.  For example maybe finding a number pattern that can be used or using a fraction to get the out come I need.  Or if there is any other mathematical way to the get the same goal.

Comment: If you found a way to halve the digits in a number without any loss of precision (and without changing the base), then you could repeat the same procedure and halve again, and again... In the end, you could represent all numbers with $1$ single digit. Which is a roundabout way to say that no, it's not possible.

Comment: @dxiv - so why not change the base?

Comment: Changing to a higher base will lower the number of digits, indeed, but you'll have more possible digits in each position.